# Renderer2, ViewChild and ElementRef. Why do we need/use such things in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm quite new to Angular and I've discovered that there's something like `Renderer2`, `ViewChild` and `ElementRef` for the sake of handling DOM rather than accessing it directly. And the articles I've come across say that manipulating DOM directly is a bad idea so we should use those Angular offering wrapper, service whatever it is. So it gets me wondering, in what point is handling DOM directly a bad idea? Any insight would be appreciate!

Comment: I would say the primary reason is that Angular re-renders the view with it's change-detection cycle.So, changes (ideally) should happen in a way that's detectable by Angular. That said - there are some examples of direct manipulation of DOM in Angular that work fine, for example styling via a Directive (see [Attribute Directives](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) and search for `nativeElement`). You just have to know that what you change on DOM does not affect the change detection mechanism.

Comment: @RichardMatsen as far as I know, el(ElementRef type).nativeElement indicates/points the related DOM itself. So in my knowledge, manipulating DOM using nativeElement seems not that different from accessing DOM directly. What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing nothing. `nativeElement` gives you access to the DOM  from ElementRef or ViewChild.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we access the native element directly we are giving up on Angular’s DOM abstraction and miss out on the opportunity to be able to execute also in none-DOM environments such as native mobile, native desktop, web worker or server-side rendering.

Remember that Angular is a platform, and the browser is just one option for where we can render our app.

So what you do is to give this responsibility to these classes.

Comment: So, Angular will do some sort of re-form/construct/format it depending on the environment with those Angular offering wrapper service?

Comment: Correct. It will protect you.

Answer (score 2):

Handling the dom directly in Angular is a "bad idea" when you need server-rendering or using a webworker where it does not work.It also makes creating unit testing easier as you are not manipulating the dom.